# Give eclipse more heap space for compiling projects?

Tags: windows, eclipse, macos, memory, heap-memory

I'm trying to compile really large program in eclipse (inherited it). When attempting to build the project, I get an out of heap space exception, so I can't ever compile it completely.

Can I update the max amount of heap available to eclipse? This faq says I can put this in the ini file (or at least I'm interpreting it that way):

-Xmx512m

to give it more heap memory. Is this correct? I'm using 3.5, galileo. I don't see any -Xmx256m type parameters in my eclipse ini file to begin with, so not sure if this is correct.

Thanks

Comment: I wanted to provide this answer as I had to do this for my MAC and there is a great video link to help with this!!! http://www.brooksandrus.com/blog_assets/screencasts/eclipsejvmheap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add -Xmx512m in the ini file on new line in the end.